# Making a click event only affect child of parent class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an expandable list of search filters for my site. Where each category has subcategories. I am using Bootstrap so I opt'd to use a customized version of the BS accordion. I have it so when you click a "parent" category the font awesome "plus" icon beside the parent turns into a "minus" to show collapsing thew list as the next action (as normally seen).

**For example:**

```
+Computers

+Phones

-Tablets

   Android Tablets

   Windows Tablets

   Apple iPads
```

The problem is, if you click Tablets to expand it as shown in my example above then click it again to collapse the list of tablets, it will toggle all of the icons for every other parent accordion list with an active plus icon to the minus even though they're collapsed.

**Here's my jquery:**

```
$('.categories').click(function(){
var collapsed=$(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus-square-o');

$('.categories').find('i').removeClass('fa-minus-square-o');

$('.categories').find('i').addClass('fa-plus-square-o');
if(collapsed)
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-minus-square-o')
});
```

I feel like there has to be a better solution available than how I am trying to make it happen. Can I write jquery to only impact the element actually being clicked without having to use tons of ID's and excessive jquery to account for each ID? I feel like a new ID for each list could get pretty messy as we may have 30+ expandable lists, not to mention the potential that there could be a child list of a child in the main list (trying to account for any possibility and make it scalable as these categories will be dynamic and not hard-coded) like so:

```
-Tablets

  -Android Tablets

    +Asus Tablets

    +Nvidia Tablets

    -Nexus Tablets

        Nexus 7"

        Nexus 10"

    +HTC Tablets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it simple:

```
$('.categories').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o').toggleClass('fa-minus-square-o')
});
```

Comment: Isn't this just removing or adding both classes to the li?

Comment: Yes and no, all list items are initialized with the minus class, this will toggle OFF on click and the other one (plus) will toggle ON on click. Keep in mind that it only targets the LI that has been clicked on ($(this)).

Comment: Thanks rsn, this is working in the sense of not affecting other accordions with the same class, however the 'minus' font-awesome icon it calls doesn't appear instead it shows as a broken img/icon and the 'plus' icon stays intact. Any suggestion? I made a codepen because JSfiddle wasn't working with expanding/collapsing. http://codepen.io/crescentfresh/pen/BzBvYa

Comment: It seems to be working in your codepen just fine, or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems you changed the HTML a tad since my answer above. For your situation, make sure you're targeting the <i> tag, so: $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus-square-o").toggleClass("fa-minus-square-o");

Comment: @rsn thank you that worked! I was messing with the HTML and didn't realize it was auto-saving globally. I really appreciate your help. Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling class on li and style the li:before with content: "-" or content: "+" depending on active class.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the code you provided instead of:

```
$('.categories').find('i').addClass('fa-plus-square-o');
```

You should use:

```
$(this).find('i').addClass('fa-plus-square-o');
```

You could do something like this:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.categories').on('click', function() {
    var elm = $(this).find('.subcategories');
    var hasClass = elm.hasClass('activeSub');
    $('.activeSub').removeClass('activeSub');
    if(!hasClass)
        elm.addClass('activeSub');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f1au458w/1/)**